# What is NotificationChannel?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I recently read that `NotificationChannel` is a new feature in android o.

```
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel=new NotificationChannel("default", "test", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
```

I am not sure what this code does.
I couldn't understand the android documentation.

Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a kind of channel category where all the notifications of that category for your app come together. If you have an app that has multiple type of notification (alarms, infos, ...) you can create these channels with their own parameters. In the system app settings of the app, in the notifications section, you will find these categories and the user can enable/disable these channels. Just for a try, open an app setting for instance Chrome, there are notifications about Browser, downloads, private browsing, media playing, sharing...

Comment: So if I have 2 notifications from chrome, 1 is from downloads and 1 is from a website then both would have a different notification?

Comment: Yes. As a user you can disable only the downloads channel for example